# If...Then statement for "if value is present in a specified column"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write an `If...Then` condition such that:

> If the value of cell A3 in Sheet1 is present in column A of Sheet2 then...

I have tried with this code but it doesn't work (Error) :

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A") Then
...
```

Comment: It would help if you included the error code and description in your question.

Comment: Have you tried `IF Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Text = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Text THEN ...` ?

Comment: Thanks to reply)) After the "Then" I have a long code which is working... I'm almost sure that the problem comes from my condition.... Do you think  she is right?? Thanks a lot))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're getting an error here, but your `If..Then` condition is definitely not working the way you're hoping/expecting it will.

You're trying to compare a single value (the value of A3 in Sheet1) to an entire column (column A in Sheet2), which is definitely not the same as looking to see if that value is *in* that column.

You can use the `Range.Find` method to determine whether a value is present in a given range, as shown below.

```
Dim varFindThis As Variant
Dim rngLookIn As Range

varFindThis = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
Set rngLookIn = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

If Not rngLookIn.Find(varFindThis, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) for more details on the function and how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, v1 As Variant, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
    v = r1.Value
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r2, v) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "its there"
    Else
        MsgBox "its not there"
    End If
End Sub
```