# Delete entire row when a value exist in a second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets: sheet1 and sheet2. I have a value in cell A3 (sheet1) which is not constant. And many files in sheets2.

What I would like to do, is when the value in cell A3 (Sheet1) is the same as the value in the column A (Sheet2), it will delete the entire row where is find this value (Sheet2).

This is my attempt. It doesn't work: no rows are deleted.

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Text = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Text Then
    Dim f As String
    f = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")        
    Set c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(f)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(c.Address()).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [If...Then statement for "if value is present in a specified column"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148953/if-then-statement-for-if-value-is-present-in-a-specified-column)

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken? At a glance it looks like this is because your `If` condition will always be false except in the edge case of Sheet1!A3 = Sheet2!A1.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not finding anything with the `.Find()`. Since you're not checking it for `is Nothing` you don't know. Also, `.Find()` retains all the search parameters set from the last time you did a search - either via code or by hand in your spreadsheet. While only the `What` parameter is required, it's always worth setting the most critical parameters (noted below) for it, you may want to set them all to ensure you know *exactly* how you're searching.

```
Dim f As String

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Text = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Text Then
  f = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
  Set c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(What:=f, Match:=[Part|Whole], _
          LookIn:=[Formula|value])
  if not c is Nothing then
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(c.Address()).EntireRow.Delete
  else
    MsgBox("Nothing found")
  End If
End If
```

Go look at the [MS docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to see what all the parameters and their enumerations are.

Answer (score 0):

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For x = 1 To Rows.Count

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1).Value Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete

Next x

End Sub

Comment: Hope this works for you, it worked for me.  I have the entire if statement on one line though.