# Delete entire row when a value exist (With sheets)

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets: sheet1 and sheet2. I have a value in cell A3 (sheet1) which is not constant. And many files in sheets2.

What I would like to do, is when the value in cell A3 (Sheet1) is the same as the value in the column A (Sheet2), it will delete the entire row where is find this value (Sheet2).

This is my attempt. It doesn't work: no rows are deleted.

```
Dim varFindThis As Variant
Dim rngLookIn As Range

varFindThis = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3")
Set rngLookIn = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")

If Not rngLookIn.Find(varFindThis, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then

Dim f       As String

f = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
'Since i didn't got that clear, here above you must create a code to declare "f" as whatever you want

Set c = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Find(f)

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(c.Address()).EntireRow.Delete

End If
```

Any Solutions?? Thanks)))

Comment: I cannot test the code but I think you don't need the brackets in `Range(c.Address)` because you're accessing a property of the range object.

Comment: Bravooooo ;) Thanks you so muchhhhh Matteo))))

Comment: Why are you reposting [the same question as 4 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206068/delete-entire-row-when-a-value-exist-in-a-second-sheet)?